# Why float, double and long double gives the same output?

Tags: c++, precision

It might seem a dumb question but I am very confused about it. I wrote a simple program as follow:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
 int main() 
{ 
float a = 12.555555555555;
double b = 12.555555555555;
long double c = 12.555555555555;

cout <<a<<endl; 
cout <<b<<endl;
cout <<c<<endl;
return 0; 
}
```

Although I am using different data type with each variable but the result of output is same for all these variables and that is 12.5556. I was expecting different precision for double and long double as compared to float. I am using DevC++ IDE.

Comment: By default `std::cout` only shows a few decimal points. The linked question explains how to print mode decimal points.

Comment: Next time you better check true values in a debugger

Comment: What were you basing your expectation on? It's better when you don't know to have minimal expectations, you'll learn quicker that way.